# how to hide textfield and auto layout the constraint in swift

Tags: swift

so i have a segmented control in my project.I want to hide and auto layout my button.But the problem if i just hide the textfields and labels the button under my segmented control still not moving.So there is a space between my segmented control and next button.I want to move my next button up if i click no on my segmented control.

-if i click yes on segmented control
The next button under my segmented control will constraint my textfield and show all textfields and labels under my segmented control

-if i click no on segmented control
The next button under my segmented control will constraint to my segmented control and hide all textfields and labels under my segmented control

thanks for all the answers

[the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XVN5.jpg)

Comment: Create height constraint Outlet and set it's constant to 0 when you want to hide it.

Comment: Use UIStackView for better effect

Comment: You would need to create height constraint use the outlet and depending on the selection of the segment set it height constraint to 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick example of how you could change the position of the button depending on the segment switch.

Below image shows dragging the auto layout height between Segment switch and button
[image: Image to show the outlet which is created]

Below Image shows using outlet and type needs to be NSLayoutConstraint
[image: Image to show the settings for outlet]

In your ViewController.Swift the code should look something like below.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var switchControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBOutlet weak var heighConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func switchPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    switch switchControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    {
        case 0:
            // here you can see the constant is being set, this will determine the
            //  position of your button. You will need to set the correct position.
            heighConstraint.constant = 150
        case 1:
            heighConstraint.constant = 200
        default:
            break;
    }

  }
}
```

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: thanks for the answer but if i have bottom constrait on next button to superview so the next button not moving.Do you have another idea?

Comment: i think an idea about make 2 next button and i will hide another one

Comment: So my approach to this would be to put all the textfield in a view and hide the view and use the heightconstraint.constant to be like 20. So the button would move under your segment switch.

Comment: Hi @IndraSen to help you out i have created a simple project with my approach you can view it on my [bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/chirag1990/autolayout/src/master/)

Comment: Hi @IndraSen let me know if that help. So i can update the answer.

Comment: hi @chirag90 sorry for late reply,i think that will work.I already solved my problem.Yesterday my constraint cant move bcs i add another bottom constraint on label.Reallly appreciate the answer thanks