# Show/hide subview when changing button state

Tags: ios, swift

### What i'm trying to achieve

I have two buttons, `yes/no`. When `yes` is pressed a subview needs to be generated right under it and when `no` is pressed the subview need to disappear(not just hide, but remove itself).

After doing some search i have reached the conclusion that what i need is a dynamic view.

### What i tried to do

I have created the buttons and now i'm trying to write the code for the view, so at the end i will have to connect the buttons to the code.

This is my UIView Class:

```
class FormView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    viewSetup()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

private func viewSetup() {
    self.backgroundColor = .red
}
}
```

and this is how i tried to create the view:

```
    var formViewOrigin = selectFormView.frame.origin
    formViewOrigin.y += selectFormView.frame.height

    let formViewWidth = selectFormView.frame.width
    let formViewHeight = selectFormView.frame.height
    let formViewSize = CGSize(width: formViewWidth, height: formViewHeight)

    let myview = FormView(frame: CGRect(origin: formViewOrigin, size: formViewSize))

    myview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor)
    myview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectFormView.bottomAnchor, constant: 24)
    myview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectFormView.trailingAnchor)
    myview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionTextField.topAnchor, constant: 50)

    let bigView = scrollView.viewWithTag(1)
    bigView!.addSubview(myview)
```

### The problem

The view is being generated, but it is not in the place that i want it to be(right under my buttons), instead it is at the end of the `bigview`. I have tried to change the constraints but i think they don't have any impact, because i also commented them and nothing happened. Does anyone have any idea on why is this happening?

To give you a better visual understading of what i'm trying to do here is an image: [formview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xq5Tb.png)

FormView has to appear between `description` and `selectFormView`.

`selectFormView` is the view that contains the buttons.

Comment: Hi, i have just answered similar question on SO, you could also have a look at that and see if that helps you. [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51186857/4056108). One of the comments under the answer also has my bitbucket repo, which may help.

Comment: @chirag90 Sure, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sol1**

```
let myview = FormView(frame: CGRect(origin: formViewOrigin, size: formViewSize))
myview .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
let bigView = scrollView.viewWithTag(1)
bigView!.addSubview(myview)
myview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionLabel.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
myview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectFormView.bottomAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true
myview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectFormView.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
myview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionTextField.topAnchor, constant: 50).isActive = true
myview.heightAnchor.constraint.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Note : this also involves removing the constraint between the description and select view as not to have constraint confliction  , and after removing myView reAdd it

**Sol2**

make a view in IB and set it height constraint to 0 and make this to toggle show/hide

```
self.myViewH.constant = show ? 300 : 0 
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: I completely removed decription's topAnchor constraint from IB and set it in code, but it doesn't go down in page when `formView` comes into `bigview`. Basically when `yes` is pressed i set this: `view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: descriptionTextField.topAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true` and when `no` is pressed i set this: `self.descriptionLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: selectFormView.bottomAnchor, constant: 24).isActive = true`.

Comment: when you create the constraint add identifier to it and remove the old one before adding the new

Answer (score 0):

you should make autoLayout constraints after adding UIView into view

> remember that if you add UIView with constraints before adding that in another view , the UIView lose your constraints when its add to the destination view